# android extra arg is null when passed from intent into target activity

Tags: android

In  TrainingDetailFragment  I need to start a SwimlogListActivity  to display a list of all swimlogs related to the Training detail.

So in my TrainingDetailFragment, I wrote an Intent and passed the training_id as an extra ( debugger log: mItem.id : 2 )

```
public class TrainingDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    ....
    Intent swimlogs = new Intent(getActivity(), SwimlogListActivity.class);
    swimlogs.putExtra("trainingID", mItem.id);
    startActivity(swimlogs);
```

and in the SwimlogListActivity, I test if I can get the trainingID arg ..

```
 public class SwimlogListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SwimlogListFragment.Callbacks {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swimlog_list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) {
        String trainingID = intent.getStringExtra("trainingID");
        Log.i(TAG, "SwinglogListActivity - onCreate() with trainingID: "  + trainingID);
    }
```

but I get a trainingID  null.....   SwinglogListActivity - onCreate() with trainingID: null

where could I be wrong ?
btw Happy 2014 !!

Comment: Does mItem.id give a string or an int?

Comment: Is mItem.id  is a int ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think your mItem.id is integer, so you simply replace your code of `SwimlogListActivity` with this:

```
...
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
if(mIntent != null) {
    int trainingID = mIntent.getIntExtra("trainingID", 0);
    Log.i(TAG, "SwinglogListActivity - onCreate() with trainingID: "  + trainingID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... that's it ... forgot to check it back

Answer (score 0):

Almost sure `mItem.id` is not a String , if it's an int for example, get it with `intent.getIntExtra`

Answer (score 0):

```
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (extras != null) {
     String datas= extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
     if (datas!= null) {
       // do stuff
    }        
 }
```

for more info: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)